# no print output in flutter 3.3

Tags: flutter, dart, printing

Before switching to flutter 3.3 everything worked fine

The essence of the problem: When testing on the emulator, I see in the console how the prints are displayed. But, if I plug in a real device, I don't see any output. Why?

Here are my two buttons:

```
Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(50),
                  child: ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {
                    _getCurrentLocation();
                    print('Тык точно был!');
                  }, child: Text('Test'))
              ),
              ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {print('Text tipo tyt');}, child: Text('Test2'))
```

and of course I don't see any console output

Comment: ```Use debug mode during development, when you want to use hot reload.```

Comment: Use log('Text tipo tyt'), it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try **log** inserted of **print**

```
 log('Тык точно был!');
```